# How add linear gradient fillColor for line with highcharts

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I need create a line with shadow, from line to top. In docs I didn't find any info about this. Help me please!
Thanks
[image]

Comment: See the answer from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022569/highcharts-lineargradient-fill-with-fixed-upper-bound/41060050#41060050 The difference is that the gradient boundaries are chart.plotTop and the lowest point in the series.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to reverse your `y`as follow :

```
 yAxis: {
        reversed: true,
    }
```

And Here is an [**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-reversed/) of reversing Axis.